# Free monitor calibration tool

Tags: display, calibration

I'd like to calibrate my monitor for editing images from my digicam at my office PC.  Currently the photos are looking quite horrible and tweaking the default monitor
settings didn't help. any ideas? I'm using an ATI graphics card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you take a screenshot? (Sorry, just had to.)

Do you need to do real color calibration as well, or just the usual balancing, gamma, and contrast settings?

For one, you should try [QuickGamma](http://www.quickgamma.de/indexen.html). I will warn you, though, when I used a proper calibration tool, I discovered that my display was not of high enough quality to calibrate correctly (Acer X203W).

Oh, sorry, I forgot to link you to this very important page:

http://epaperpress.com/monitorcal/index.html

Comment: thx - i think the usual balancing should be enough ..

Answer (score 1):

There's some online stuff for LCD monitors [here](http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/)